# Extjs add listener after page load

Tags: extjs, widget

I'm documentum xcp developer, xcp UI is developed in extjs and we have a tool to create UI. In the UI we have only one option to set initial value to widget. I can call function to set initial value

My requirement is to restrict user from entering hyphen in number field and numeric values in text field.

On the page we have menubar and items linked to page. I want to added "afterrender" listener to a page.

```
var page = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('panel[title=Document Search]')[0];
page.on("afterrender", function(){ alert('after render called ...');

});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have to tried to use vtype in your textField?

More informations here : 
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.VTypes

For example :

```
{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    name: 'email',
    fieldLabel: 'Email Address',
    vtype: 'email'  // requires value to be a valid email address format
}
```

In this example, you are creating a textfield which allows only email address. 
You have 4 types of "vtype" :

- alpha
- alphanum
- email
- url

It's also possible to create a custom vtype like this example from the doc :

```
    // custom Vtype for vtype:'time'
    var timeTest = /^([1-9]|1[0-9]):([0-5][0-9])(\s[a|p]m)$/i;
    Ext.apply(Ext.form.field.VTypes, {
        //  vtype validation function
        time: function(val, field) {
            return timeTest.test(val);
        },
        // vtype Text property: The error text to display when the validation function returns false
        timeText: 'Not a valid time.  Must be in the format "12:34 PM".',
        // vtype Mask property: The keystroke filter mask
        timeMask: /[\d\s:amp]/i
    });
```

Hope this will be helpful for your problem!